# What is the difference between these two components?

Tags: battery-charging, raspberry-pi

What is the difference between the two products below?

[PowerBoost 1000 Charger - Rechargeable 5V Lipo USB Boost @ 1A - 1000C](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2465)

[USB LiIon/LiPoly charger - v1.2](https://www.adafruit.com/products/259)

I want to charge a battery that I am using with a Raspberry Pi project.

Comment: Why don't you embed the pictures in your question and add details of the input and output specifications for each device rather than have a hundred EEs do this. In other words do some work yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The [PowerBoost 1000 Charger](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2465) includes a boost converter that can handle up to 1000mA (1A) at 5.2V output:

> Solder in the USB connector and you can plug in any iPad, iPhone or iPod for 1000mA charge rate.

While the [USB LiIon/LiPoly charger](https://www.adafruit.com/products/259) is only a battery charger, that means that you can only get whatever voltage the battery is at out of it (somewhere between 3.7~4.2V).

Most RPi setups are powered by 5V in its micro-USB connetor or at the header. So if you dont have a step-up converter, the first option is a more versatile solution.

If you are already powering your RPi directly with your battery and that works well for you, the second one will be enough. (However I dont think you can charge the battery while powering the RPi at the same time).

So if you need/want to charge your battery and power your RPi at the same time, back to the first option.

> With a built-in load-sharing battery charger circuit, you'll be able to keep your power-hungry project running even while recharging the battery!

From: [Adafruit PowerBoost 1000C overview.](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-powerboost-1000c-load-share-usb-charge-boost/overview)

Comment: Some variants of the RPi can be powered directly from a LiPo battery on their 5V input, but USB peripherals might complain.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams -- nice, I didn't know that. I added some more info on the answer to account for that case. Thanks.